# What does "vats" mean?

Tags: meaning

> The dimensions of this empire are awesome. Its population runs into hundreds of millions, drawn from every nation on Earth. It dominates the skylines of our cities – their tallest buildings are no longer cathedrals or temples but multi-storey vats filled with workers.

https://www.1843magazine.com/features/death-of-the-office

Comment: It means what the dictionary says – a large container. It's an unusual imagery though, perhaps intended to make the office and the people therein seem like an industrial component.

Comment: Ah okay, when I looked it up it said "a large tank or tub used to hold liquid, especially in industry" which seemed so unfitting that I assumed there was another definition the New Oxford American Dictionary missed.

Comment: It reminds me a certain style of cartoon which depersonalises people by showing them on conveyor belts and so on, as part of a process.

Comment: I never metaphor I didn't like!

Comment: @HotLicks not sure what you mean.

Comment: @AustinConlon - https://quotesfromthepast.com/i-never-met-a-man-i-didnt-like/